# C-sharp winform ADO.NET

Tags: c#

I am trying to develop a module that can be refer to as transaction in my Pharmacy management system using c#, but what I want to do is I want a situation whereby subtotal of each item sale we be stored in mysql database and total amount will be stored at once and is going to be accumulated for each transaction in mysql database too.

```
private void TransactionSave()
{
    try
    {
        if (RxtTransact_Id.Text == "" || QuantitySold_Transaction.Text == "" || RxtUnit_Price.Text == "" ||
            RxtProduct_Name.Text == "" || cmbTransaction_SalesMan.Text == "" ||
            RxtCustomer_transaction.Text == "")
        {
            MessageBox.Show("The required field(s) can not be left empty", "Transaction erreor", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
        }
        else
        {
            conn.Open();
            commandd = new MySqlCommand("insert into transaction( Transaction_id, quantity_sold, unit_price, product_name, salesman, customer_name, date_time, sub_total, total_amount) values (@Transaction_id, @quantity_sold, @unit_price, @product_name, @salesman, @customer_name, @date_time, @sub_total, @total_amount)", conn);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("Transaction_id", RxtTransact_Id.Text);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("quantity_sold", QuantitySold_Transaction.Text);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("unit_price", RxtUnit_Price.Text);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("product_name", RxtProduct_Name.Text);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("salesman", cmbTransaction_SalesMan.Text);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("customer_name", RxtCustomer_transaction.Text);
            DateTime dt = Convert.ToDateTime(dateTimePicker1.Value);
            dateTimePicker1.Value = DateTime.Parse(dt.ToShortDateString());
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("date_time", dateTimePicker1.Value);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("sub_total", RxtSubTotal_transaction.Text);
            commandd.Parameters.AddWithValue("total_amount", RxtTotal_Transaction.Text);
            commandd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
    }

    conn.Close();
}
```

[image: GUI Snapshot]

Each time I click addtocart, I want total amount to be saving at once and continue to be accumulated for each transaction.

Comment: I'm just curious, why there's a Sales Id and Transaction Id but I can't see any search button or any search by control in your form ?

Comment: what i want to do is that, each time user click one addtocart subtotal must be saved for every transaction and and total amount must also be saved at once and for a particular transaction.take for insatnce if someone should by different products that is up to 5 all the amount must accumulate together into total amount texbox and must be stored once in mysql database

Comment: Then why don't you store the sub-total to a variable each time Add to Card is been clicked, then at the end get the sum before saving it to your db ? It's basic so you should be able to do that or did I misunderstood something ?

Comment: how am i going to print receipt from the two tables, i mean table for sub total and the other one for grand total.You no what , i really want something dynamic .I rthink this is the problem of id.I do not really understand very well on how to relate the two id together so that whenever ithe id of subtotal change, the id of grand total must move to the next number in the table.I know is possible but i do not know how to do it .Pls, if you have done something on Pharmacy Mgt System that contains this kind of problem am trying to solve share it with me.

Comment: Thanks for the concern